# How to set cookie with some delay or find how old is cookie in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I set a cookie **returning_user**

```
 cookies[:returning_user] = { value: "anonymus" , expires:  (Time.current + 1.hours) }
```

Now I want to perform some action if the cookie is **10min** older, so is there any way to find out how old a cookie is.

If no, then how can I set that cookie after 10mins.like in Javascript I can use setTimeout for that

```
setTimeout(()=>{
.....setcookielogic will come here...
},10*60*1000);
```

I am new to ruby, hope someone can help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When cookies are sent in an HTTP header, their expiration time is NOT sent with them, just the value. However, if you want to know when the cookie is set, put the creation time in the cookie (or another cookie). So maybe something like:

```
> cookies[:returning_user_cookie_set_time] = {value: Time.current + 1.hours, expires: (Time.current + 1.hours)}
```

This makes sense since you are trying to maintain state with a piece of data...kind of what cookies are for. As opposed to trying to maintain state by manipulating the cookie syntax.

Of course if you are using rails, you can just keep the data in the session and achieve the same thing without risking someone seeing/manipulating your backend data.

Comment: Thanks @MattPo, this helped me, can you tell me how can I do this with session

Comment: The session hash will be available between multiple calls to your server. So in your controller you can set a session variable with session[:returning_user_cookie_set_time] = Time.current + 1.hours, and then in a later request you can read it by expiration_time = session[:returning_user_cookie_set_time]